# Rails ActiveRecord has_many through association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

When I query directly against my database I get the expected result, but not in rails. I'm guessing it has to do with my associations and something bad I said about Ruby 3 years ago.

Postgres SQL Query:

```
SELECT users.email, members.software, members.files 
FROM users INNER JOIN members 
ON members.user_id = users.id 
WHERE members.region_id=2
```

> Result: "dan@gmail.com";t;t "dan@test.com";t;t

BUT from rails c:

```
>   ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT users.email,
> members.software, members.files FROM "users" INNER JOIN "members" ON
> "members"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "members"."region_id" =
> 2←[0m> => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, email: "dan@gmail.com">, #<User id:  nil, email: "dan@test.com">]>
```

That snippet was the resulting query from pasting in what I have tried to create in my controller and hard coding the region id:

```
User.joins(:members).select("users.email, members.software, members.files").where(members: {region_id: params[:id]})
```

These are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :members
      has_many :regions, :through => :members
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, :through => :members

end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :region
end
```

Is it the way I have associated my models or something else that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting is `active_relations` object.

you can access the attributes like this

```
users = User.joins(:members).select("users.email, members.software as software, members.files as files").where(members: {region_id: params[:id]})

users.each do |u|
  p u.email
  p u.software
  p u.files
end
```

Comment: Right, so when I have that top line in my controller as @members = ... and the bottom part in my view it tells me undefined method `softare' for #<User id: nil, email: "dan@gmail.com"> in a ruby error page.

Comment: The query is returning a collection of users, you will have to iterate through the members of the individual users to get the software attribute you want. If you want to get the software and files of all the members of that user you can do something like. @members.each do |member| softwares = member.members.pluck(:software) files = member.members.pluck(:files). Pluck returns an array of all the attributes matching the symbol name, giving you the abilityt o iterate through that and show all the files and softwares

Comment: I don't understand why I have to iterate over the results like @JulioGMedina recommended. It works, but it seems like there would be a more direct way.

Comment: you could query for members directly rather than querying for members as opposed to users.